# Building net6 project with BundlerMinifier on Docker - Object reference eception

Tags: docker, .net-6.0, docker-build

I faced "object reference" exception while dockerizing net6 app. I am using BundlerMinifier to bundle specific js files.

my bundleconfig.json

```
[
 {
"outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
"inputFiles": [
  "wwwroot/js/site.js"
],
"minify": {
  "enabled": true,
  "renameLocals": true,
  "alwaysEscapeNonAscii": true,
  "gzip": false,
  "preserveImportantComments": false
 }}]
```

and here is part of my docker file

```
RUN dotnet add package BuildBundlerMinifier
RUN dotnet restore "View.Site.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "View.Site.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

At this point build operation failed with "object reference" exception in Bundler and minifier inside. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution;
Do not commit your builded and minified files to your repo.

Minifier can not delete and re-create output files on docker environment as i see.

You need to choose your way; either process localy and commit output files or do not commit local outputs, let Minifier do its job.